# Intelligent distribution of tasks among workers in Celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, distributed-computing

After a week of trying and searching, I didn't get any results and I would appreciate your help.

Summary:
I have 4 workers and there is an app.task inside each worker.
Every day, these 4 workers have to do nearly thousand tasks.
The problem is how to intelligently divide tasks among these 4 workers.

more details:
My current code divides 1,000 tasks by 4, and then each worker is given 250 tasks. Why do I share? Because I have to apply_async the tasks at the beginning of the work. (so each worker has a separate queue)
Workers execute tasks without any problems, but a challenge arises when some workers execute tasks faster and end up without tasks, while some workers may be executing their tasks for more hours.


What am I looking for?
We are looking for a way to have all 1,000 tasks in one queue without dividing them and automatically remove these 4 worker tasks from this 1,000 queue and execute them, in this case the other workers will finish their tasks almost together.

**My codes are in 4 files:**

celery.py:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import,unicode_literals
from celery import Celery


app=Celery('celery_app')
app.config_from_object('celery_app.celeryconfig')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

celeryconfig.py:

```py
broker_url='amqp://guest@localhost//'
result_backend='rpc://'
include=['celery_app.tasks']
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1

task_routes={
    'celery_app.tasks.app_1000':{'queue':'q_1000'},
    'celery_app.tasks.app_1000':{'queue':'q_1002'},
    'celery_app.tasks.app_1000':{'queue':'q_1004'},
    'celery_app.tasks.app_1000':{'queue':'q_1006'},
    'celery_app.tasks.app_timeout':{'queue':'q_timeout'},
}
```

tasks.py:
There are many codes in the tasks.py file, see this link [in GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arezooebrahimi/celery_distribution_tasks/main/celery_app/tasks.py).

api.py:
This is a simulated api, for example, if I send the number 1000, it is like it has to do 1000 tasks and this thousand tasks are divided between 4 apps.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException,Request
from celery_app.tasks import app_1000,app_1002,app_1004,app_1006,get_active_queue
import random

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/run_tasks")
async def run_tasks(num_of_tasks:int):
    try: 
        app_list = [app_1000,app_1002,app_1004,app_1006]

        for i in range(0,num_of_tasks, 4):
            app_list[0].apply_async() 
            app_list[1].apply_async()     
            app_list[2].apply_async()     
            app_list[3].apply_async()     
    
        
        return 'ok'

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
    

@app.get("/get_active_queue")
async def get_active_q():
    res = get_active_queue()
    print(res)
    return 'ok'
```

Please guide me how to do this?
If something was dumb, comment so I can explain more.

My code is in the following link: https://github.com/arezooebrahimi/celery_distribution_tasks

Comment: could you share an example of task and how you run tasks( `celery beat`, `standalone process`, `web server` etc )?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar My code is in the following link: github.com/arezooebrahimi/celery_distribution_tasks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you want your workers to pick up tasks as soon as they are free and all the workers have same tasks. Using a single queue, with all the workers listening on it should work and this is how it is used by default. If you are having long running tasks, you might want to set `worker_prefetch_multiplier=1` in the celery [configuration](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-worker_prefetch_multiplier). I don't understand what made you start with 10 different queues instead of a single queue for all the workers.

Comment: thank you
The problem is that workers have to run different apps on tasks. For example, it is possible that we have ten different types of apps, and according to these ten apps, we want ten workers, and each worker is responsible for performing tasks with a specific app. My code is in the following link:
https://github.com/arezooebrahimi/celery_distribution_tasks

Comment: By default, worker_prefetch_multiplier is 4, and 1 or 4 does not have much effect on the work process and does not solve my problem.

Comment: However, the value of worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1 is inserted in celeryconfig.py.

Comment: Why do you want dedicated workers for each of the tasks? Unless you are unsure about the order of task queuing and afraid of single task filling majority of the task queue, I don't see the benefit of your architecture. If the order is same and predictable as in the code, you should use a single queue with multiple workers listening on it. Also what do you mean by `app` here? Because every app has same configuration in the code you shared. How are the apps different?